Unity for integral domain
We know an integral domain is a commutative ring having no zero divisors. Is it necessary that unity should exist for an integral domain.

This is a matter of convention and it varies across authors. Some include unity in the definition of a ring, some exclude it.

Will it alter anything in definition when ring has no unity.
